# Adding data into method variable

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a question that's a little out of my knowledge scope. To put it simply, is there a way to add data into a method variable?

For example, lets say I have a website with lots of articles. Each article may be written by a different author. "articles" and "user" are in separate tables, but linked via "user_id".

I can get it to display articles easily enough inside the HTML (big ol list). But I don't know how to attach the username or user first/last name to each of that. I know I need to somehow "update" the method variable for this to work.

models.py

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default='')
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    articles = Articles.objects.all
    context = {'articles': articles}
    return render(request, 'projsapp/index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<tbody>
    {% for piece in articles %}
        <h1>{{ piece.title }}</h1>
        <h3>{{ piece.description }}</h3>
        <h6>Article by {{ piece.username }}</h6>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

The method variable in this case is "articles". Obviously "piece.username" doesn't work, so how do I attach it? Thanks!

Comment: `{{ piece.user.username }}` ?

Comment: Yes! Boy that was simple. Thank you @rnevius !

Comment: Added as an answer, @Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each article (or `piece`) does not have a `username` property. Instead, each article has a `user`, which in turn has a `username` property. So you need to get the article's `user`, and get the `user`'s `username`:

```
{{ piece.user.username }}
```